# Shortcut iPhone/iPad app to send email to a specific address?

Tags: ios, email

I send lots of emails to a small number of people.  Rather than having to send emails to them through the native Mail app, I'd like to have an app that I can "click" on that automatically has a specific address already filled in and seeks only a subject and message-contents.

I'd like to have three of these, each doing the same thing, but going to different email addresses.

I've never written an iOS app and don't feel like learning how, but I haven't yet found a way to either create forms or encapsulate macros or other paths to doing what I want.  I've tried doing this by navigating to a webmail "send email" screen via the Safari browser, filling in the *To* field, and then saving it as a shortcut, but when clicked on the screen appears without the email.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two apps which support something like this:

- [Drafts](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/drafts/id502385074?mt=8)

  Note application with the ability to define actions for these notes based on the standard URL scheme. Sending mails to pre-defined addresses is easily possible
- [LaunchCenter Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/launch-center-pro/id532016360?mt=8)

  Quick starter for apps, using URLs as well. Using an URL with the mail recipient included will open Mail with an empty mail already addressed correctly.

Comment: This got me thinking.  I created a web page whose contents were a redirect to a mailto URL.  I loaded that page in safari and then saved it to the home screen and voila, I got what I needed.  Thanks for sparking the inspiration for solving this!

Answer (score -3):

I' using workflow apps for doing this

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Could you please elaborate on this, e.g. with screenshots? As it stands, it's a rather poor answer and got an automatic downvote from the system.